# Powershell Move-ADObject wildcard

Tags: powershell, wildcard

We want to have an automatic OU assignment in our ActiveDirectory.
I tried to use the Move-ADObject cmdlet. But since we want that every object which CN starts for example with "Notebook" to move in to the "Notebooks" OU I have to use some kind of a wildcard but I couldn't figure out how to do it yet.

The code I use (I know it doesn't work):

```
Move-ADObject CN=Notebook*,CN=Computers,DC=ivstlu,DC=ch -TargetPath 'OU=Notebooks,DC=ivstlu,DC=ch'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
get-adcomputer -filter "name -like '*Notebook*'" -searchbase "CN=Computers,DC=contoso,DC=net" | move-adobject -targetpath "OU=Notebooks,DC=contoso,DC=net"
```

Comment: That worked thanks! Now I tried to make a .ps1 file with this code but the file does not execute the code. I tried to add the 'Import-Module ActiveDirectory' command but nothing changes

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot that the execution of .ps1 files is disabled by default